# Can DispatcherPassError be set selectively for some URLs in AEM?

Tags: apache-2.4, error-handling

In AEM (Adobe Experience Manager) Dispatcher configuration, can the directive `DispatcherPassError` be set only to requests with some specific selector in the URL?
I'd like the dispatcher to return a servlet response untouched for some requests and pass the rest to Apache with its `ErrorDocument` etc. directives.
Is it possible?

I tried adding `RewriteCond` before `ErrorDocument` directives to exclude some URLs, but it did not work. The conditions seem to be working only when `DispatcherPassError` allows error handling by Apache.

I tried also adding some pattern matching before the `DispatcherPassError` directive, like `<FilesMatch>` or `<LocationMatch>`, but Apache complained that such directives are not allowed here.